# Magento2.4.5 google brower console display jquery-migrate.js:100 JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.bind() is deprecated

Tags: jquery

Magento CE 2.4.5 I install some theme after google brower console display follow info ,how to fix?

```
JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.click() event shorthand is deprecated
JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.resize() event shorthand is deprecated
JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.unbind() is deprecated
JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.delegate() is deprecated
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your theme might be using older syntax of jQuery, you can ask for support if you have paid for the support **or** change the code by yourself with new code as show in below example.

Example :-

**Change your code from**

```
jQuery("#your_element").click(function () {
    // Your code
});
```

**to**

```
jQuery("#your_element").on('click', function () {
    // Your code
});
```

**You can refer to official changelog for JQuery UI library** https://jqueryui.com/changelog/1.13.2/

[image]

**Below is the code change in official JQuery UI library repo**

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/commit/b53e7beb6884a8de7710146112bc48aecd8737b4

[image]

Comment: If this answer works as your expected, please mark it as accepted. That indicates your issue is solved and makes it easier for others with the same issue to find a verified answer. And that would be great if you click the upvote button for the answer in case you feel it is useful.